# Общий итог по запросу

Tags: oracle

Нужен полный итог по таблице. Пример: основной большой запрос (c кучей join и where) возвращает таблицу model, amount, price, type

Нужен итог по полям amount и price: model, amount, price, type. И в последней строке итоги по столбцам amount, price

Пробовала так:

```
select * from
(
Select mk.model, pr.amount, pr.price, mk.type from product pr
left join maker mk on mk.model=pr.model
where amount>10) tabl
union
select 'ИТОГ', sum(amount), sum(price), ' ' from tabl
```

Пишет,

> tabl invalid

Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Во первых, для использования union оба запроса должны возвращать одинаковое число столбцов и совместимые типы данных в соответствующих столбцах (из вики).  Во вторых, напишите сам запрос полностью, может в нем закралась синтаксическая ошибка. Ну и в третьих укажите типы данных которые возвращают запросы.

Comment: Сам запрос верный, он работает, и количество столбцов у объединяемых столбцов верное.
Я так понимаю проблема в том, что oracle  не может посчитать суммы по таблице tabl? Так как для него такой таблицы нет?
Типы - model-text, amount - integer, price-integer, type-text

Comment: Верный запрос или нет можно решить если его увидеть полностью, а не где куча многоточий.

Comment: ДОбавила запрос

Comment: Так не пойдёт,  попробуйте with tabl as (....)

Comment: Большое, спасибо, с with получилось)
А можете, пожалуйста, в двух словах почему с with работает?

Comment: @ElenaKatz with делает как бы view _до_ начала выполнения основной части запроса. А внутри одного запроса обращаться к его же частям по алиасам нельзя. Еще на rollup помотрите, imho красивее выглядит, по производительности не знаю как оно

Comment: @0xdb С rollup  получилось минут за 10 до вашего ответа про with))
Спасибо большое за вариант)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select nvl(mk.model,'ИТОГ') model,
       sum(pr.amount) amount, sum(pr.price) price, mk.type
  from product pr
  left join maker mk on mk.model=pr.model
 where amount>10
 group by rollup( (mk.model, mk.type) )
```

В group by надо обязательно указать такие колонки, что бы обеспечили уникальность всех строк. Двойные круглые скобки так же необходимы, без них будут подводится промежуточные итоги по каждой модели. rollup в итоговых записях делает поля участвующие в группировке NULL, собственно по этому признаку мы и отличаем итоговую запись и заменяем NULL на 'ИТОГ'.

И второй вариант, не знаю будет он быстрее или нет:

```
with Q as(
  select mk.model, pr.amount, pr.price, mk.type 
    from product pr
    left join maker mk on mk.model=pr.model
   where pr.amount>10
)
select * from Q
union all
select 'ИТОГ', sum(amount), sum(price),' ' from Q
```

P.S. посмотрел планы выполнения на небольшой тестовой табличке: cost для первого варианта заметно ниже, чем для второго. В первом делается 'group by for rollup' и один проход по таблице. Во втором - два отдельных прохода по таблице. Но cpu-cost в первом случае выше. Так что выбрать какой из вариантов быстрее можно только на реальных данных в конкретной ситуации.

**UPD** Вариант 3:

```
select model,
       nvl(amount,sum(amount) over()),
       nvl(price, sum(price) over()),
       type
  from (
        select mk.model, pr.amount, pr.price, mk.type 
          from product pr
          left join maker mk on mk.model=pr.model
         where pr.amount>10
        union all
        select 'ИТОГ', NULL, NULL, ' ' from DUAL
      ) A
```

Если в каких то из столбцов в изначальных данных может быть NULL, то nvl на эти колонки можно заменить на `decode(model,'ИТОГ',sum(price) over(),price)`.
По общему cost данный вариант аналогичен первому, но cpu-cost значительно ниже и так же один проход по таблице.

Comment: Большое спасибо)) С rollup у самой вышло) Думала это ед. вариант
Самой интересно теперь как быстрее)

Comment: Вариант с rollup, как известно, предпочтительнеий, но быстрей с ним почему-то не получается. Я загнал в тестовые таблицы по милиону записей. С union  за ~2 сек. вернулся в sqldevelopr, с rollup ~6 sek. План отдал предпочтение по cost union. tkprof показал, что union ест меньше проца, но много IO, и полное время у union ~8 сек., у rollup ~12. В общем надо на конкретных данных и на конкретном железе решать.

Comment: @0xdb У rollup все таки group by, если записей много он будет промежуточный результат (считай всю выборку) писать в TEMP. union судя по всему в temp не пишется (хотя мог бы) и данные обрабатываются на лету

Comment: Ну да,  идеального варианта нет. rollup 48M в темп написал.

Comment: @0xdb Кстати, вы про какой union говорили, который из CTE или который третьим вариантом ? И вы не забываете union all, без all он будет хуже.

Comment: Я имел в виду второй вариант из вашего ответа, с all конечно. А СТЕ что это?

Comment: @0xdb CTE - commot table expression так по научному зовется `with` :)

Comment: А, что-то не подумал, что это латинскими буквами ))

Comment: Понял наконец, я не совсем точно выразился в комменте, union я имел в виду - with  () записи union all итог. Поэтому и про темп не понял - всё, что в cte в темп пишется, куда ещё 1000000 записей.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример того, что Вы хотите сделать, но в моем случае делается 2 раза select:

```
select mk.model, pr.amount, pr.price, mk.type 
   from product pr
   left join maker mk on mk.model=pr.model
   where pr.amount>10
union
(select 'ИТОГ', sum(pr.amount), sum(pr.price), ' ' 
   from product pr       
   where pr.amount>10
   group by 1)
```

Comment: А скобки во втором селекте для чего? group by 1?